# greensock TweenMax javascript - kill looping tween

Tags: javascript, tween, gsap

I created a looping tween using [Greensock javascript](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) and I got it to loop using a function, maybe this is not the best way to loop, if you know a better way please advice,  but basically when I try to kill the tween using this method, it doesn't work.

My code:

```
var dvdTween;
function playDVD()
{
 dvdTween = TweenMax.to($("#bigDVD"), 4, {css:{rotation:+1440, transformOrigin:"150px 150px"},ease:Expo.easeNone, delay:7, onComplete:playDVD});
}
```

/// Later in a function I call

```
dvdTween.kill(); /// but this does nothing.
```

Again, there may be a better way to loop a tween, and this may be my issue, but as of now this tween keeps on calling the function after I "kill" it.

Thanks for your tips and help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should indeed work - I'd love to see an example set of files that shows it not working. I wonder if you're running into a scope issue or something - are you sure "dvdTween" is referencing the tween in the context you're calling it? Try adding onCompleteScope:this to your tween.

Two other tips:

1) You can loop a TweenMax infinitely by setting repeat:-1, like:

```
TweenMax.to($("#bigDVD"), 4, {css:{rotation:1440}, repeat:-1});
```

2) You can kill all the tweens of a particular object using TweenMax.killTweensOf() like:

```
TweenMax.killTweensOf($("#bigDVD"));
```

Comment: Hi Jack! haha :) Thanks so much for the awesome response. I will try to be brief. My code worked but it kept calling the onComplete even after I killed the tween. I tried your method and it works but I can't get the tween to delay. Also when the functions keeps on calling it calls bigDVD but that is a loaded div. If they go to a new page the div is not there and it causes all javascript to stop working. That is why I was trying to kill the tween, but again the onComplete kept on going, thus restarting the tween again. Would you like me to post my code? It's long and messy :( but works :)

Comment: Yeah, I'd recommend creating a separate, isolated (simplified) example file because often times that will help identify the problem. Feel free to post your file over in the GreenSock forums at http://forums.greensock.com.